# Umbraco Up gradation Proposal

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

We had developed an Umbraco based site for one of client way back using version 4.7.1.

Now when the client is demanding more additions to the existing project our development team has suggested the up gradation of Umbraco from 4.7.1 to 7.1.

Main challenges we face are

- Have to completely redo the project.
- Some of the packages used at that time are obsolete.
- Convince the client for up gradation.

The team is not entirely sure of the benefits of up gradation, i mean client does not possess much technical knowledge .
Can anyone help on this.
Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have upgraded Umbraco installation from version 2 all the way up to version 6, and if you followed the upgrades, that would be fine.

Version 7 on the other hand is completely new and requires a different approach for datatypes, custom sections, etc..., and will require extensive rewrites.

The Umbraco upgrade (files and datbase) might not be such an issue, this is usually well tested by the umbraco team, but the extensions you wrote might pose some serious hurdles.

Upgrading to version 6 would be an option, though the benefits will not be that visible for the client. It is more stable, and has a lot of support from the community.

Upgrading to version 7 would also mean the editors need to get used to the new interface (which might be an issue, depends if you have 1 or 100 editors), lots of code rewrites (missing packages and datatypes), and a phase where the developers need to get used to a different coding style in the Umbraco 7 back-end (all done with angularjs).

Version 7 looks very nice though, and clients might be inclined to go for it and spend the money. If not, and you are on a budget and time limits, you should move as far as version 6.

Comment: We know 4.7.2 has some technical flaws and it is fixed in later versions can you give some compelling reasons so that we can suggest client because of these features its better to upgrade to umbraco 7

Comment: In my opinion, the only real and valid advantage is the much improved UI experience in Umbraco 7. I believe this is sufficient for most clients to want an upgrade as it will improve their productivity when managing the website. And of course do not forget the wow factor when switching from something as dated as the previous umbraco interface (goes all the way back to version 2, released somewhere in 2005).

Answer (score 1):

It's always tempting to go for the latest & greatest version.  Personally I'm waiting for v7 to get bedded in for a year to let other people work out what needs patching and I'll be developing new Umbraco projects in v6 certainly for 2014.

Given how bad the experience of v5 was I don't think the great reports of v7 are enough to tempt me this year.

On upgrading, the reality is, (http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/11/14/the-upgrade-myth.aspx) as Niels Hartvig put it - upgrading Umbraco is a myth.  To go up from 4.7 to 4.11 is certainly do-able; I've done it following this guide (http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/36855-upgrading-from-472-to-4111).

But to try to upgrade from v4 to v6 or v7 is going to take longer & result in a worse site than building a new site from scratch.  A lift-and-shift job that involves the switch to MVC from asp.net forms alone is going to take more time than a new site will take to build.

The real options you have are:

- Justify a new build in v6 or v7
- Build on what you have in v4

Depending on your budget, expertise & priorities either option could be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to upgrade from 4.7 up to the end of the 6 branch without any major issues, I performed a similar upgrade recently. If your site uses lots of packages or custom data types, I wouldn't bother jumping to 7, as most of them won't work with the new API.

The main issues that you are likely to run in are the change in version of ASP.Net, and you'll almost certainly have to update some of your 3rd party packages along the way. I documented my upgrade [here](http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2014/03/upgrading-umbraco).

If they desperately want 7, I'd consider a rebuild from scratch, as a LOT changed between 4.7 and 7. The main benefits of upgrading to the end of the 6 branch are that you get a big improvement in back office performance (especially when you have multiple editors working at once), an improved media library, and a number of nice bug fixes. Most of the changes are under the hood though, so your client might only notice the snappier response of the back office and the media library, so it could be quite hard to justify the cost to them.